# How to order by number ASC but force to order same value from another field in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let say I have a table like this:

| Sequence | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | John D |
| 4 | Alex H |
| 5 | John M |
| 1 | Sell T |
| 3 | John D |
| 2 | Alex H |

I want it ordered like this

| Sequence | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sell T |
| 2 | Alex H |
| 4 | Alex H |
| 2 | John D |
| 3 | John D |
| 5 | John M |

To order by the sequence field but if the name field has values that are the same, on the first occurence of the next row then all same name should fall under it respecting the order of the sequence as well.

I prefer t-sql solution.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that your data fully represents what you want to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks I've edited the question abit.

Comment: . . That is what I suspected you want.  The second part of my answer answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example data and ambiguous explanation suggest that you just want two `order by` keys:

```
order by sequence, name
```

However, I suspect that you want to order names by their minimum sequence.  If so, you can use window functions:

```
order by min(sequence) over (partition by name), name, sequence
```

For your sample data, these would result in the same ordering.

Comment: Awesome , it worked! I should really try learning partitions! Thanks!